# How to limit the results in a view?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, view, feed, aggregator

I have created four categories in feed aggregation. which show the results about 100. I want to create a view of aggregation item and in aggregation item i use the feed category to select my category which i have created in feed aggregation. Now here i want the category to show only latest five results not the all 100 results for each category.

How it is possible???
Any idea about this?

Answer (score 4):

Addressed in [Drupal View display - setting a limit for the query results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2566958/drupal-view-display-setting-a-limit-for-the-query-results)

To sum: use the Items do display field in the view's basic settings.

Answer (score 0):

Just limit your pager to display only 5 items and click on full pager.Also add a sort criteria of node:created date. and select desc...u vl get the top 5..

hope it helps..!!!